What is the reason for the gack Error ID: 885490792-1007256 (490349768) on Embedded Service Deployment creation?
What is the reason for the  gack Error ID: 885490792-1007256 (490349768) on Embedded Service Deployment creation?
When I try to create a new Embedded Service Deployment, I receive an error gack Error ID: 885490792-1007256 (490349768)
Why is this happening and is there any way to avoid this?

Underlying error under this gack id is the following:
Error: Duplicate key OBSOLETE MESSAGING SETTINGS (attempted merging values 0MjEi000000OizCKAS and 0MjEi000000O0dBKAS)

The error is basically due to multiple Messaging Settings with the same label because of which the Salesforce is unable to identify a unique developer name from the backend as there are multiple entries coming during the search by label and throws the error.
The solution here is to change the label from Common Shared Label to Common Shared Label (1)

